# ASP.Net MVC - How to store a value in a safe way in a MVC Controller during concurrent requests?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

While uploading an excel file in Angular JS + MVC project , I get the currently being uploaded file via

```
// DEFINE THE PATH WHERE WE WANT TO SAVE THE FILES.
string sPath = "";

sPath = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UploadFilePath"];

System.Web.HttpFileCollection hfc = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;
```

But after this validation is done ,if it is successful, user will be presented with the confirmation pop up. User clicks submit on it , the file should now be saved to a physical location.

But now I do not have the file access. How to hold the file of the previous request.

```
System.IO.File.Copy(filePath, Server.MapPath("~/Uploads"));
```

But filePath I do not have now . How to achieve the desired functionality and save the file ?

Do I need to store it in some variable in some thread safe way ?

Comment: Why can't you do it all i.e. validation+upload in a single request?

Comment: Why aren't you saving the file regardless of weather it is validated? Storing the file path in the DB, if you need to delete it you can do it afterwards, otherwise your going to be storing the file in memory for quite some extra time

Answer (score 0):

You could use [System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath.aspx)

Or, [HttpContext.Cache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.cache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

But like Dandy suggests a better solution would be to do your validation and save in the same request. And give a success, or, fail+message response to your user within that single request.